# Get user by userId in ROOM

Tags: java, android, database, kotlin, android-room

I want to take event by id but it returns unit.

Entity:

```
@Dao
interface EventDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM event_table WHERE eventId= :myeventId")
    fun getEventByEventId(myeventId: Int): LiveData<Event>
}
```

Repository:

```
class EventRepository(private val eventDao: EventDao){
    fun getEventById(myeventId: Int): LiveData<Event>{
            return eventDao.getEventByEventId(myeventId = myeventId)
    }
}
```

Viewmodel:

```
class EventViewModel (application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {
 private val readEventById = MutableLiveData<LiveData<Event>>()
fun getEventById(eventId: Int) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            readEventById.postValue(eventRepository.getEventById(eventId))
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling it on user fragment:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
        val event = eventViewModel.getEventById(currentUserId)
    }
```

but it returns unit. How can i return event by userId?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `ViewModel` class, you should include a public `LiveData<Event>` value that returns the `readEventById` live data object:

```
val selectedEvent: LiveData<Event>
    get() = readEventById
```

Then, in the user `Fragment`, you should instead add an `Observer` on `eventViewModel.selectedEvent`. When you call `eventViewModel.getEventById(currentUserId)`, you don't worry about the result. Instead, the `Observer` will let you know the `LiveData<Event>` was updated and you can handle the value this way.

This is the proper approach since you're getting the data from the database asynchronously.

Comment: It works clearly.

Answer (score 1):

We can use withContext for returning values from a coroutine scope, it is defination from documentation : "Calls the specified suspending block with a given coroutine context, suspends until it completes, and returns the result." for details visit the documentation [withContext](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/with-context.html)

in your case you can use like this

```
suspend fun getEventById(eventId: Int): LiveData<Event> {
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        eventRepository.getEventById(eventId)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: it returns: androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData@c24988bt